# How do I set a template argument value to the value of another tag?

Tags: django

I have a template tag to generate the url as follows;

```
<li><a href="{% url 'blog_archive' year='2013' %}">Archive</a></li>
```

I want the '2013'(year) to be generated automatically based off the current year. There is a tag that can do this `{% now 'Y' %}` however i cannot use it inside the existing template tag as it just produces errors.

Do i need to create a custom tag to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do additional computation in the template? You are sending it to the view anyways.

Comment: Default params to urls better does at the `urls.py` See example below

Comment: What you are looking for is 'nested template tags'. Search for it on SO. There are a lot of questions regarding this. Find the one that suits your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to include one tag inside another like this.

You can create an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), which stores the tag's result in a context variable instead of outputting it.

The example assignment tag in the docs is for a template tag `get_current_time`, which you could use instead of the `{% now %}` tag.

In your `mytags.py` template tag module:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

In your template:

```
{% load mytags %}
{% get_current_time "%Y" as year %}
<li><a href="{% url 'blog_archive' year=year %}">Archive</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, i can tell this is a much neater and logical way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

May be better decision is would be set default parameter at the `urls.py` ?

Example `urls.py`:

> ```
> from django.utils.timezone import now
> ...
> urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
>     url(r'^.../$', 'blog_archive', {'year': now().strftime('%Y')}),
> )
> ```

Comment: Or it could even be computed in the view.

Answer (score 0):

[That](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#date) is what you want.

Maybe this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'blog_archive' year=value|date:"Y"  %}">Archive</a></li>
# just pass the datetime object as 'value'
```